# shading between dates each time period in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some daily time series and I am trying to shade in certain regions of the plot using `ggplot`. I would like to shade in the months between July and August of each year. I am trying with `geom_rect` and I can get it between two dates just not between the same dates for each year.

Data:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyquant)

data(FANG)
data <- FANG %>% 
  filter(symbol == "FB")


data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = adjusted)) +
  geom_line()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can manually create a dataframe describing regions to shade.

```r
library(lubridate)
shade <-
  data %>% 
  transmute(year = year(date)) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  mutate(
    from = as.Date(paste0(year, "-07-01")),
    to   = as.Date(paste0(year, "-08-31"))
  )
shade
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>    year from       to        
#>   <dbl> <date>     <date>    
#> 1  2013 2013-07-01 2013-08-31
#> 2  2014 2014-07-01 2014-08-31
#> 3  2015 2015-07-01 2015-08-31
#> 4  2016 2016-07-01 2016-08-31

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = shade, aes(xmin = from, xmax = to, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf)) +
  geom_line(data = data,  aes(x = date, y = adjusted))
```

[image]